# MAUI app targeting IOS fails to pair using VS2022 r17.7.3

Tags: c#, ios, maui, visual-studio-2022

I have a MAUI application targeting Android & IOS. Having moved it from Xamarin (rewriting it in the process), the Android app is published so now I'm moving on to the IOS.

I've upgraded the Mac to the latest XCode and (since doing that) have paired to it successfully. However, I realised thatthe project wasn't actually targeting IOS, so I ticked that. Now I can't pair at all - it seems to connect OK, but then fails right at the end and disconnects, The error I'm left  with is...

```
**Could not install workload 'ios'. Details: System.IO.IOException: The system cannot open the device or file specified. : 'NuGet-Migrations'
   at System.Threading.Mutex.CreateMutexCore(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew)
   at System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name)
   at NuGet.Common.Migrations.MigrationRunner.Run()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.Configure()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(IFirstTimeUseNoticeSentinel firstTimeUseNoticeSentinel, IAspNetCertificateSentinel aspNetCertificateSentinel, IFileSentinel toolPathSentinel, Boolean isDotnetBeingInvokedFromNativeInstaller, DotnetFirstRunConfiguration dotnetFirstRunConfiguration, IEnvironmentProvider environmentProvider, Dictionary`2 performanceMeasurements)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)**
```

So far I've repaired VS2022 and created a default project targeting only IOS - this fails too, so at least the problem isn't the project. As I say, unticking the target IOS option solve it and I can pair OK, but obviously that's no use as its the whole point of pairing in the first place!

Has anyone else seen this??

Many thanks.

So far I've repaired my local VS2022 (Windows 11) and created a small test project, which also fails.